# How to save high score using SharedPreferences on Android Studio?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, saving-data

I am using Android Studio to created a game currently I am trying to save my high score. I have managed to get it working however when I exit out of the application the high score seems to reset. Is there any way I can save the score even after I exit the application.

My code:

```
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.dreamchase.HIGHSCORE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

private int highScore = Game.prefs.getInt("HIGHSCORE", 0);

if (player.getScore() > highScore) {
                    highScore = player.getScore();
                    Game.prefs.edit().putInt("HIGHSCORE", highScore).commit();
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried using SharedPreferences yet? If not give it a try and then come back if you run into any issues. [Any of these options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) are viable for persistent data storage.

Comment: please show the code that pertains to your question

Comment: Hi, I did use SharedPreferences. I have added my code above if you'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: try your code in 2 separate lines i.e. get an instance of Editor and then in second line use putInt() and commit

Comment: Thank you I think that did the trick! :)